# Need help to understand SQL query (oracle10g)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm new in SQL and need little help to understand parts in this SQL statement

```
select BUY_VALUE,
    SELL_VALUE,
    RATE_DAY,
    RATE_TIME
from ( SELECT TRIM (b.ticker),
           TRIM (TO_CHAR (b.buy_value, '9999999.99')) BUY_VALUE,
           TRIM (TO_CHAR (b.sell_value, '9999999.99')) SELL_VALUE,
           b.currency, 
           TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 'YYYYMMDD') rate_day,
           TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24MISS') rate_time 
         FROM portal.gpb_bank_quotes b
         WHERE b.ticker = 'GAZP'
     )
```

1. what is `b` (b.buy_value) ?
2. `FROM portal.gpb_bank_quotes` - is that table name? Is it possible that it delimited with `.`
3. ahhh too difficult ///

Thanks in advance

Comment: `portal.gpb_bank_quotes b` .. got it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `b` is a [table alias](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0140__Table-Joins/SupplyingTableAliases.htm) for `portal.gpb_bank_quotes`.  This is handy so that you don't have to type `portal.gpb_bank_quotes.buy_value`, etc.
2. Yes.  `portal` is a [schema](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm), and `gpb_bank_quotes` is a table in that schema.

Comment: Jack Maney thanks, but how it can be <...> from (SELECT TRIM (b.ticker), <...> I thought after FROM it has to be table name, but here it goes: (SELECT TRIM... What is it?

Comment: see my EDIT above - this is a "subquery"...

Comment: Yes, it's a subquery (http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php).  You might want to consider picking up some books and/or tutorials on SQL:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/books+sql

Answer (score 3):

`b` is an alias for the table/view `gpb_bank_quotes` which is located in the schema `portal`.

EDIT - as per comment from OP:

The `SELECT ... FROM ( SELECT... FROM...)` is just using the inner SELECT as a [subquery](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php).

Comment: so inner 'select' should return table name for outer 'from'?

Comment: it doesn't return a table name but it returns a set which behaves like a table or view... see the link http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php please...

Comment: finally I got it, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The same result for this query could also be obtained without the outer select.  The TRUNC on SYSDATE is also redundant if specifying the date format to TO_CHAR

```
SELECT TRIM (TO_CHAR (b.buy_value, '9999999.99')) BUY_VALUE,
       TRIM (TO_CHAR (b.sell_value, '9999999.99')) SELL_VALUE,
       TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') RATE_DAY,
       TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24MISS') RATE_TIME 
  FROM portal.gpb_bank_quotes b
  WHERE b.ticker = 'GAZP';
```